# Term-level access to clock rate

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation, singleton-type, clash

I'd like to access the clock rate (in Hz) as a term-level value, so that I can use it in counters.

One way I've been able to come up with so far involves unpacking the type-level `Dom`ain into its clock period (in ps), and then converting it into a clock rate. However, this requires an extra `KnownNat ps` constraint that will then infest everything that tries to use it, all the way up to `topLevel`:

```
clkPeriod :: forall dom gated name ps. (dom ~ Dom name ps, KnownNat ps) => Clock dom gated -> Integer
clkPeriod clk = natVal (Proxy :: Proxy ps)

clkRate :: (dom ~ Dom name ps, KnownNat ps) => Clock dom gated -> Integer
clkRate clk = 10^12 `div` clkPeriod clk
```

Another way, that avoids introducing the extra `KnownNat` constraint, is to import `Clash.Signal.Internal` and pattern-match on the `Clock`, since it contains an `SNat` witness of the period:

```
import Clash.Signal.Internal (Clock(..))

clkPeriod :: Clock dom gated -> Integer
clkPeriod (Clock _ period) = snatToInteger period
clkPeriod (GatedClock _ period _) = snatToInteger period

clkRate :: Clock dom gated -> Integer
clkRate clk = 10^12 `div` clkPeriod clk
```

but this crashes the synthesizer
(guess I shouldn't be importing `Clash.Signal.Internal`):

```
*** Exception: Clash.Rewrite.Util(566): 
Can't create selector ("Clash.Normalize.Transformations(1136):doPatBndr",1,0) for:
($dKnownNat23000 :: GHC.Natural.Natural)

Additional info: TyCon has no DataCons: 
Name {nameSort = User, nameOcc = GHC.Natural.Natural3674937295934324782, nameLoc = UnhelpfulSpan "<no location info>"} GHC.Natural.Natural3674937295934324782
```

Here is a full module exhibiting this problem (I tried synthesizing it with `:vhdl` to get the above error):

```
module Test where

import Clash.Prelude hiding (clkPeriod)
import Data.Word
import Clash.Signal.Internal (Clock(..))

type FromHz rate = 1000000000000 `Div` rate
type Dom25 = Dom "CLK_25MHZ" (FromHz 25175000)

topEntity
    :: Clock Dom25 Source
    -> Reset Dom25 Asynchronous
    -> Signal Dom25 Bit
topEntity = exposeClockReset board
  where
    board = boolToBit <$> r

    r = regEn False (counter .==. 0) (not <$> r)
    counter = register clkrt $ mux (counter .==. 0) (pure clkrt) (pred <$> counter)
    clkrt = fromIntegral $ hideClock clkRate

clkPeriod :: Clock dom gated -> Integer
clkPeriod (Clock _ period) = snatToInteger period
clkPeriod (GatedClock _ period _) = snatToInteger period

clkRate :: Clock dom gated -> Integer
clkRate clk = 10^12 `div` clkPeriod clk
```

My question is, is there a way to reify `clkRate` in the term level without introducing any extra `KnownNat` constraints, or importing any `Internal` modules?

Comment: Do you have a self-contained minimal example that generates the exception?  Otherwise, it's hard to know if a potential solution will be any better than what you've already tried.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr: I don't have a minimal example yet; the real-life self-contained example would be the one at https://github.com/gergoerdi/chip8-clash. However, I think there is something fundamentally broken about the `Clock` argument you can access via `hideClock`: https://github.com/clash-lang/clash-compiler/issues/348#issuecomment-419611322

Comment: @K.A.Buhr I've edited my question to contain a minimal example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Clash 1.0.0, this can be done without the creeping `KnownNat` constraints OR without importing any `Internal` module. The trick is to use `knownDomain` to get the `SDomainConfiguration` for a given clock domain, which will contain an `SNat period` for the length of a single clock cycle (in picoseconds). By pattern matching on the `SNat` constructor, the `KnownNat` witness is brought in scope.

```
clkPeriod :: forall dom. (KnownDomain dom) => Clock dom -> Integer
clkPeriod clk = case knownDomain @dom of
    SDomainConfiguration _ rate@SNat{} _ _ _ _ -> natVal rate

clkRate :: (KnownDomain dom) => Clock dom -> Integer
clkRate clk = 1_000_000_000_000 `div` clkPeriod clk
```

Here's the updated toplevel definition:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NumericUnderscores #-}
module Test where

import Clash.Prelude hiding (clkPeriod)
import Data.Word

createDomain vSystem{vName="Dom25", vPeriod = hzToPeriod 25_000_000}

topEntity
    :: Clock Dom25
    -> Reset Dom25
    -> Enable Dom25
    -> Signal Dom25 Bit
topEntity = exposeClockResetEnable board
  where
    board = boolToBit <$> r

    r = regEn False (counter .==. 0) (not <$> r)
    counter = register clkrt $ mux (counter .==. 0) (pure clkrt) (pred <$> counter)
    clkrt = fromInteger @Word32 $ hideClock clkRate
```

I've tested that this works with synthesis, and the division to convert period length to clock rate is done at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this has been acknowledged by the Clash primary developer Christiaan Baaij as a Clash compiler bug in [Issue #348](https://github.com/clash-lang/clash-compiler/issues/348#issuecomment-419611322).  To quote from his comment in that issue report:

> So the issue is that the Core we're getting is pattern-matching on something of type `Integer` and exposing the internals of its representation; something the compiler obviously doesn't handle. I'll create a work-around/hack to always pick the branch where the `Integer` fits inside the [-2^63 .. 2^63-1] range, since Clash currently "erroneously" translates `Integer` to 64-bit numbers anyways.